# $\partial y/\partial t=y''+(ax+b)y'+cy$ - Separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the equation that looks like this;

$$
\frac{{\partial Y\left( {x,t} \right)}}{{\partial t}}
=
{D}\frac{{{\partial ^2}Y\left( {x,t} \right)}}{{\partial {x^2}}}
+
\mu(E_1x+E_0)\frac{\partial Y(x,t)}{\partial x}
+
\alpha Y(x,t)
$$

The list of derivatives I used are
$$
F(\frac{\partial Y(x,t)}{\partial t})=\frac{\partial U(k,t)}{\partial t}
\qquad
F(\frac{\partial Y(x,t)}{\partial x})=ikU(k,t)
\qquad
F(\frac{\partial^2 Y(x,t)}{\partial x^2})=-k^2U(k,t)
$$

$$
F(x^nY(x,t))=i^n\frac{d^n U(k,t))}{dk^n}
\quad\rightarrow\quad
F\left(x\frac{\partial Y(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)
=i\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\left(ikU(k,t)\right)
=-U(k,t)-k\frac{\partial U(k,t)}{\partial x}
$$

Using Fourier transform + Separation of Variables gives
$Y(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$

$$
\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{DX''+\mu (E_1 x+E_0)X'+\alpha X}{X}=\lambda
$$
The first and middle term gives
$$
T(t)=e^{\lambda t}
$$

The middle and last terms together is 
$$
DX''+\mu (E_1 x+E_0)X'+(\alpha-\lambda)X=0
$$
I used Fourier Transform to solve this equation, $F(X(x))=\hat{X}(k)$
$$
-Dk^2\hat{X}+\mu E_1\left(-\hat{X}-k\frac{\partial \hat{X}}{\partial k}\right)+ik\mu E_0\hat{X}+(\alpha-\lambda)\hat{X}
=
(-Dk^2-\mu E_1+ik\mu E_0+a-\lambda)\hat{X}
-k\mu E_1\frac{\partial \hat{X}}{\partial k}
=0
$$
This is just ordinary differential equation
$$
\int \left(-\frac{D}{\mu E_1}k
+\frac{iE_0}{E_1}
+\frac{\alpha-\lambda-\mu E_1}{\mu E_1}\frac{1}{k} \right)dk
=\int \frac{1}{\hat{X}}d\hat{X}
\qquad\rightarrow\qquad
-\frac{D}{2\mu E_1}k^2
+\frac{iE_0}{E_1}k
+\frac{\alpha-\lambda-\mu E_1}{\mu E_1}\ln k=\ln \hat{X}
$$
$$
\hat{X}=
exp\left(
-\frac{D}{2\mu E_1}k^2
+\frac{iE_0}{E_1}k
\right)
k^{\frac{\alpha-\lambda-\mu E_1}{\mu E_1}}
$$

With the aid of mathematica, inverse Fourier transform is
$$\begin{aligned}
X(x)&=
\sqrt{2} \left((-1)^{\frac{\alpha}{\mu E_1}}+(-1)^{\frac{\lambda}{\mu E_1}}\right) (i E_0 - i E_1 x) \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha-\lambda+\mu E_1 }{2 \mu E_1}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{\alpha-\lambda+\mu E_1}{2 \mu E_1 };\frac{3}{2};-\frac{\mu (-E_0+E_1 x)^2}{2 D E_1}\right)
\\&+
E_1 \sqrt{\frac{D}{\mu E}} \left((-1)^{\frac{\alpha}{\mu E_1}+1}+(-1)^{\frac{\lambda}{\mu E_1}}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha-\lambda}{2 \mu E_1}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{\alpha-\lambda}{2 \mu E_1};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\mu (-E_0+E_1 x)^2}{2 D E_1}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $_1F_1$ denotes Hypergeometric1F1

**Now here is my question. Somehow I got the answer, but how do you erase $\lambda$ that was used for separation of variable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't erase $\lambda$.  There is a family of solutions, parameterized by $\lambda$ (and also a second constant scale factor $\kappa$ in $\hat{X}$ that you omitted when integrating the ordinary differential equation, where you could have added $\ln \kappa$ to the $\ln \hat{X}$).

The specific values of $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are determined by the initial values  and/or boundary conditions.

Comment: Oh...... so $\lambda$ is determined by initial condition....

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I'll add $\kappa$ to the equation

Comment: Or, I could just multiply C at the last equation, though.